# How to `truffle migrate` to private permissioned network?

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, truffle-migration, quorum, migration

I am running a private permissioned network and would like to use Truffle `v5.0.1` for deployment. I use it according to [the documentation](https://truffleframework.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/running-migrations):

1. Compile my project with `truffle compile` so that the `./build` folder with the appropriate json files appears.
2. Deploy my project with `truffle migrate --network private`, BUT:

**I get an error:**

> Error: Number can only safely store up to 53 bits.

Here is my deployment script:

My `1_initial_migration.js` looks as follows:

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("Migrations");
var MyTokenContract = artifacts.require("MyTokenContract");

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
    deployer.deploy(Migrations, {from:accounts[0], gas: 4500000, gasPrice:0});
    deployer.deploy(MyTokenContract, "arg1", "arg2", {from:accounts[0], gas: 4500000, gasPrice:0});
};
```

I have set up a network object whithin the `truffle-config` file named private:

```
private: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(myPrivateKey, `http://ip_address_to_network:22000`),
  port: 22000,
  network_id: "*",
  from: "0x....", 
  production: true
}
```

**EDIT:**
If I use `HDWalletProvider(myPrivateKey, http://ip_address_to_network:22000)` without the port specification `22000` in the URL, then I don't get the above error! Then it seems that everything works fine, but I get **NO return or confirmation at all on the console. How do I find out whether the migration worked?**

Comment: What version of truffle are you using? What's the exact output from the command `truffle migrate`? I've tried with truffle v5 and metacoin box and migration works fine.

Comment: @Ismael have updated the question

Comment: Can you check if your node is mining transactions? I tried deploying to ganache and geth private and when deploy is complete it will show info about the transactions and the contract addresses created.

Comment: `eth.blockNumber`= didn't increase after my deployment attempt. But truffle is also NOT showing any errors. Thats not very handy to find out whats wring...

Comment: If you get no output then the transactions generated by truffle are not being mined. Check if a miner is running and accepts transaction with 0 gas price.